# in django can we pass arguments in redirect/HttpResponseRedirect to another view

Tags: python, django, redirect, http-redirect

i am trying to pass arguments like form, orm queries used in 1 view function to another without changing the url reference in url.py with redirect or httpRedirect. request.session is also not working as orm queries or form details needs to serialized or pickled before attempting to pass to another function.sorry if i sound silly as i am just learning django
below is my code.

```
views.py
.....................................

def home(request, **kwargs):
    y = blog.objects.all()
    print("******************")
    try:
     if request.user is not None:
        x = Profile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
        form = blog_form(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if request.method == "POST":
           form = blog_form(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
           if form.is_valid():
              title = form.cleaned_data.get("title")
              content = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
              types = form.cleaned_data.get("types")
              x1 = form.save(commit=False)
              x1.created_date = datetime.datetime.now()
              x1.created_by = request.user
              x1.save()
              return redirect("home")
        else:
         form = blog_form()

         return render(request, 'home.html', {'form1': form, 'y': y, 'x': x })
    except:
        print("anonymous user")
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'y': y})
 
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'form2': kwargs.get('form2'), 'p9': kwargs.get("p1")})


@login_required(redirect_field_name='my_redirect_field')
def user_comments(request, id, *args, **kwargs):
    x1 = blog.objects.get(id=id)
    n1 = comments.objects.filter(commented_blog__id=id)
    print(x1)
    form2 = comment_form(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    print(form2.is_valid())

    print(form2.errors)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form2 = comment_form(request.POST)
        print(form2)
        if form2.is_valid():
            print("--valid-----")
            comment_text = form2.cleaned_data.get("comment_text")
            x2 = form2.save(commit=False)
            x2.commented_user = request.user
            x2.commented_blog = x1
            x2.save()
            kwargs = {'form2': form2, 'usercomment': n1, 'p1': 2}
            print(request.session['p1'])
 #           HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:home', kwargs={'form2': form2, 'usercomment': n1, 'p1': 2}))
            return redirect(reverse(('posts:home'), kwargs = {'form2': form2, 'usercomment': n1, 'p1': 2}))

 #           return redirect("home", pk=id)
        else:
            print(form2.errors)
            print("not valid")
            return redirect(reverse(('posts:home')))
    else:
        form2 = comment_form()

    return render(request, "home.html", {'form2': form2, 'usercomment': n1})



url.py
............................................................


app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
         path('', views.home, name='home'),
         path('settings/<int:id>', views.user_settings, name='usersettings'),
         path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
         path('login/', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
         path('logout/', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
         path('blog/', views.create_post, name='create_post'),
         path('like/<int:id>', views.like, name='like'),
         path('unlike/<int:id>', views.unlike, name='unlike'),
         path('comment/<int:id>', views.user_comments, name='user_comments'),

]

if settings.DEBUG:

      urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)



home.html
.........................................

<div id="abc193" class="abc192" align="right">
<form method="post" action="comment/{{ joke.id }}" >
{% csrf_token %}


<button type="submit" name="submit">comment</button>
</form>
 {% for comment in usercomment %}

  {{ comment.comment_text }}

 {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endfor %}
</div>

<div id="abc198" class="abc198" align="right">

<form method="post" action="{% url 'posts:home' %}">
{% csrf_token %}

{{ form2.as_p }}

<button type="submit" name="submit">submit-comment</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you define kwargs twice?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, but if you're trying to redirect from a POST request then the only place to store values is in the query string.  You can't redirect a POST request into another POST request and have the POST data pass to the redirected URL.

Comment: there are 2 view functions have different forms and consuming same html template file. implementation is something like that view function home consist all the user posts and when any other user wants to comment on the posts it redirects to  posts/comment/<post:id> now user will fill form2 and again redirects to home page. my question is that since i am not passing any argument in home page so is there any way i can pass form2 data(which is getting save in DB), orm queries or pk of posts i am commenting so that i could render the comment data on home page.this i have tried with request.session

Comment: reverse , HttpResponseRedirect but unable to render that data. please help or correct me if my way approach is ok and is is it feasible without saving data in json or .pkl file and then deserialize.